# T-SQL pulling multiple columns of data from a single column field

Tags: t-sql

I am trying to pull 3 columns of data from one field. basically i have a field with for arguments sake a table with the following data:

- Color,
- Model,
- Year of a car.

It is itemized as `ID4` is Color, `ID5` is Model and `ID6` is Year. I can pull one data set with no problem using a filter, ex. Filter = 4, 5 or 6. But I cannot pull multiples as I just get the headers and no data at all.

Comment: Please re-phrase your question to me it makes little to no sense.  Add sample data as well as expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server 2005+, and your question really is "how do you break one column in a table into multiple named columns based on another field in the same table", here is a simple example patterned after your question.

Give this dataset:

```
declare @tbl table (id int, tag char(3), data varchar(255))

insert into @tbl values
(1, 'ID4', 'Red'), (1, 'ID5', 'Toyota'), (1, 'ID6', '1999'),
(2, 'ID4', 'Blue'), (2, 'ID5', 'Honda'), (2, 'ID6', '2000'),
(3, 'ID4', 'Green'), (3, 'ID5', 'Nissan'), (3, 'ID6', '2004'),
(4, 'ID4', 'Red'), (4, 'ID5', 'Nissan'), (4, 'ID6', '1990'),
(5, 'ID4', 'Black'), (5, 'ID5', 'Toyota'), (5, 'ID6', '2002')
```

A simple `select` statement returns this data:

```
select * from @tbl

id  tag  data
1   ID4  Red
1   ID5  Toyota
1   ID6  1999
2   ID4  Blue
2   ID5  Honda
2   ID6  2000
3   ID4  Green
3   ID5  Nissan
3   ID6  2004
4   ID4  Red
4   ID5  Nissan
4   ID6  1990
5   ID4  Black
5   ID5  Toyota
5   ID6  2002
```

This `pivot` query returns the data -- one row per car -- with Color, Model and Year as their own columns:

```
select id, [ID4] as 'Color', [ID5] as 'Model', [ID6] as 'Year'
from (select id, tag, data from @tbl) as p
pivot (max(data) for tag in ([ID4], [ID5], [ID6])) as pvt
order by pvt.id
```

This is how the output looks:

```
id  Color  Model   Year
1   Red    Toyota  1999
2   Blue   Honda   2000
3   Green  Nissan  2004
4   Red    Nissan  1990
5   Black  Toyota  2002
```